# How can I run a cronjob for a php file properly inside of c-panel?

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, cron

I am trying to run a cron-job that automates the cache rebuild function of [Woo Search Box](https://demo.guaven.com/docs/woo-search-box/) plugin.

The plugin has this dynamic cron command, that I set to run once a day at 1AM:

```
php /home/carit/public_html/index.php 16021417635f7ebe43c604a
```

I am well experienced with cron jobs inside of C-Panel but I can't figure out what prevents this cron from running. All in all, I have tried what the documentation suggests [here](https://demo.guaven.com/docs/woo-search-box/#cache), also tried `usr/bin/php` instead of `php` but it didn't make any difference.
If I run this cron-job inside my server's terminal, it works like a charm and the cache is being rebuilt. It only seems to not be working when I run it via cron-job.

Does anyone have any suggestions or ideas on why doesn't this cron-job works?

Please correct me in the comments in case I forgot to provide any key information about my problem,
Thanks.

Comment: did you try `usr/bin/php` or `/usr/bin/php` because those are two very different  things (and the second should work assuming PHP is installed at /user/bin)

Comment: Tried both. usr and /usr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that some newer versions of CentOs or Ubuntu servers use either `/usr/local/bin/php` or simply `/usr/bin/php`. If you have ftp access to the server you want the cron to run in, make sure to check for the php file in both paths recommended above before trying to use the ordinary `php` before a cron job.